# How android interprets the pattern of gesture?

Tags: android, design-patterns, pattern-matching, gesture

i want to ask something for my paper.
Anyone knows about the mechanism of android to interpret the pattern of gesture?
I mean the mechanism of gesture pattern matching in android.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the [Android gesture package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html). You can also dig through the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/gesture) in order to get more information.